# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' though Pillow is installed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Though I have installed `Pillow==7.2.0`. I am getting error "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`".I have reinstalled the `pillow` and also restarted my laptop several times but it is not working. The import section is given bellow:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import random
import time
import PIL
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import pygame
```

My code was run well few months ago. But not working now. I can't fix the problem.

Comment: in what IDE are you getting this error?

Comment: do you have more than 1 python version installed?

Comment: pycharm community edition 2019.2.1

Comment: yes... I have check out that I have installed python 3.6.4(64-bit),python 3.7.4(32-bit),python 3.8.3(64-bit)

Comment: in your vnv, please check `pip freeze` & check Pillow is there or not... I think Pillow get installed in different Python.. & you are using different python for running this code..

Comment: I got Pillow==7.2.0 in the list of modules by using 'pip freeze' command in cmd. Shall I keep only one python version in my laptop?

Comment: you can have multiple version..

Comment: Added an answer, do let me know